# Route to controller in subfolder in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

This is my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'Panel\PanelController@index');
```

This is my folders:

```
Http/
....Controllers/
................Panel/
....................../PanelController.php
```

This is my Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PanelController extends Controller {

/* some code here... */

}
```

This is what I get:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Panel\PanelController does not exist
```

I tried the "composer dump-autoload" command but still not working...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The namespace of your class has to match the directory structure. In this case you have to adjust your class and add `Panel`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;
//                             ^^^^^

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PanelController extends Controller {

/* some code here... */

}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` again?

Comment: sure :/ Maybe something changed in Laravel 5?

Comment: Oops it's a different error now: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Panel\Controller' not found

Comment: Aha that makes much more sense.. the problem now is that your controller is extending `Controller` which is one namespace level "up". Just import it by adding `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: Wow now I have this error: FatalErrorException in 5d407ee96656111b417e8f98552f6c80 line 271:
syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: This means you have a syntax error in your view. This long filename belongs to a cached view in `storage/framework/views` you can open it to find out which view it is...

Answer (score 7):

Follow three simple steps

1. append the folder name in the namespace

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;
   ```
2. Add "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;" to the controller before the class definition

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   ```
3. Add the appended folder name when invoking the controller in any route

   ```
   Route::get('foo','Panel\PanelController@anyaction');
   ```

There is no need to run "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: Just small correction, remove \ before Panel - `Route::get('foo','Panel\PanelController@anyaction');`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a controller with a subfolder as simple as:

```
php artisan make:controller Panel\PanelController
```

It automatically creates proper namespaces and files with directory.
And reference it in routes just as mentioned before:

```
Route::get('/some','Panel\PanelControllder@yourAction');
```

Happy codding!