# Laravel Route::get directly from App folder

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So in my project I have one class that is placed in `app` folder (not inside `app/http/controllers`) and has middleware just `App`.

When I'm trying to get its method from **routes.php** it's not found because it's not in controllers folder and middleware.

What should I write instead of `Route::get('/get', 'MyApi@get');` to make it all work?

Comment: Why does it have outside controllers folder?

Comment: because I don't know where to place class if I'm trying to make my own API

Comment: Make a new controller instead. That is better

Comment: php artisan make:controller NewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for your **API** you should use something like [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com), or, if you want it inside your main project, make nested folder inside your `Controllers` folder, and access it from routes like `Api\MyApi@get`.

If you **really** want it outside **Controllers** folder (absolutely no reason for it, IMHO), you need to change `RouteServiceProvider` namespace setting, to be empty string:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = '';

    // ...
}
```

Then specify full namespace for your controller and access it from wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the controllers in subfolders if you namespace them correctly. I can't think of a valid reason to not put application controllers in the application its controllers directory.

See:

- [Route to controller in subfolder in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309615/route-to-controller-in-subfolder-in-laravel-5)